# Line items without products

Tags: commerce

I would like to use an external source for Products, and skip creating commerce_product entities.

I have used hook_commerce_line_item_type_info()

```
 $line_item_types['external_product'] = array(
'name' => t('Bridged Product'),
'description' => t('Custom Line Item type that references external product data sources.'),
'product' => FALSE,
'base' => 'external_product',
'type' => 'external_product',
);
```

and hook_enable()
    commerce_line_item_configure_line_item_fields(array('my_module'));

However, I get an entity_metadata_wrapper fatal error on line_item_save() of unknown data property commerce_product.

Is it not possible to create line items without this property? Is that not what product>false does?

Comment: The documentation indeed suggests that `product => FALSE` removes the need for `commerce_product`. (Though you might try referencing a single 'bridged product' from all line items). Be aware that once customers view orders in their profiles these linked products might show up and that multiple 'bridged products' can be confusing. You could try using [Commerce Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds) (Assuming Drupal 7) to synchronize the products with your external source?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Commerce feeds isnt really feasible - the products are ~6M records (including different currencies), and iterating and doing entity saves via feeds is a huge processing bottleneck.

my code to create line items is

```
// Create the new line item.
$line_item = entity_create('commerce_line_item', array(
  'type' => external_product',
  'order_id' => $order->order_id,
  'quantity' => $item['qty'],
));

   $line_item = commerce_line_item_save($line_item);
```

but I get that error about a missing parameter (commerce_product'). I have removed the module from the sys table, cleared all cache and re-enabled the module to make sure the custom line items are registered with fields, but still a no go.